# Ubuntu not working properly in VM workstation 10?

Tags: 12.10, 10.04

I have installed VM Workstation 10 and then tried to install Ubuntu in it, but after installing, the Ubuntu screen only contains the desktop background but no other icons are displaying on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and many more when using VM Workstation. Thats when I moved to Oracle VM Virtual Box. I have not had any issue what so ever with any of my Virtual machines since.